# Rendering a 3D volume

Tags: volumetrics

I'm playing around with ways to visualize an MRI image of my head. I've extracted my brain, so there are non-zero brain voxels in the center, and zeros to the edge of the image.

I'm imagining having a corner cut out of my brain to expose its interior voxels like this: [image]

Additionally, I've also got voxel-wise statistical data that I'd like to use as a semi-transparent overlay on the anatomical.

Is this setup possible?

Comment: I think you can do this with BI, provided the format your voxel data is in is supported.

Comment: I've got it in 8-bit raw and can load it in BI.. I can't make it look like anything other than a smoke cloud though..

Comment: Hm.. I would think it would be possible with some nodes and procedural textures (I know it would be possible in cycles, if we could only get the voxel data..), but I don't know BI nodes very well and I didn't have much luck loading in some test voxel data.

Comment: I'm very excited about voxels coming soon to cycles! Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my BI setup:

material:

[image]

textures:

[image]

The first texture is a nice dense whole brain object, almost making the voxel data appear like a surface. The second texture makes the voxel values affect reflection color, which is important for *inside* the object.

I used a simple boolean modified to cut away the corner chunk:

[image]

Comment: Just curious. Did you actually get voxel data of your own head, or do you by "my brain" mean the brain that you're modelling?

Comment: I'm using an MRI of a mouse in this question.. But I have an MRI of _my_ brain that I've been playing a lot with :)

Comment: And the hospital here wouldn't even give me copies of the images from my fundus photography. :(

Comment: Awww that sucks! This was for research at a university, and they didn't mind giving me the image :) http://imgur.com/FF9U5Ql