# How to generate images from texture volumic

Tags: image

I want to generate consecutive images from a 3D texture
Here images were obtained with cross section.
In different cases these volumes can created with: 
- A cube Contains of procedural textures volumetric 
- A cube contains holes (porous). 
- A cube contains different mesh same or different colors.
These are videos that explain this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Yv2XYsCAYU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJI-yzpbKfg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPyG_fEee_o
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3oInsZ7MJM

Can you help me to get the images in all three cases.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/animating-slicing-up-an-object and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-images-as-a-3d-object and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18418/cycles-volume-rendering-3d-image-texture-ct-or-mr-dataset , and maybe: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/is-it-possible-to-give-a-texture-thickness and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15010/rendering-a-3d-volume

Comment: i use cross section with plan such as in video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOQt_qnk7DM, but i have not look texture, in your firt tutorial does not work as, compared to others I did not understand the explanations.